# GMail / GSuite delegate mailbox on mobile

Tags: gmail

Because Google (even after all these years) still hasn't made an effort to support loading delegated mailboxes into either Gmail or Inbox mobile and Outlook doesn't support it either, I was wondering if there are any mobile apps around, that do support delegated inboxes?